# Symfony 4 : choiceType doesn't show choice_value correctly

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm new with Symfony and I want to build a select option using `choiceType`.

So I add this code to `buildForm` method :

```
$builder->add('applications', ChoiceType::class, [
  'choices' => [
    '-- Choisir --' => NULL,
    'Admin' => '2',
    'Super' => '1',
    'visiteur' => '10',
    'admin local' => '98',
    'partenaire gestionnaire' => '16',
    'admin national' => '15',
    'soutien' => '11',
    'exploitant' => '12',
    'moe' => '99',
  ]
]);
```

But when I inspect HTML code I don't have the correct numbers :

```
<select id="user_applications" name="user[applications]" class="form-control">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Choisir --</option>
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
  <option value="2">Super</option>
  <option value="3">visiteur</option>
  <option value="4">admin local</option>
  <option value="5">partenaire gestionnaire</option>
  <option value="6">admin national</option>
  <option value="7">soutien</option>
  <option value="8">exploitant</option>
  <option value="9">moe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you have several solutions: either you use 'null' as a string and in the controller, you take care of retrieving it as you wish or you use '--Choisir--' as a placeholder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add some context to Le Professionnel's answer: If you take a look at the [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder) documentation, you can see that the type allows you to define a custom placeholder. Try changing your code to this:

```php
$builder->add('applications', ChoiceType::class, [
    'placeholder' => '-- Choisir --',
    'choices' => [
        'Admin' => '2',
        'Super' => '1',
        'visiteur' => '10',
        'admin local' => '98',
        'partenaire gestionnaire' => '16',
        'admin national' => '15',
        'soutien' => '11',
        'exploitant' => '12',
        'moe' => '99',
    ]
])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove **'-- Choisir --' => NULL**, by another value, you can't use null value.

**If a value is null or similar, symfony replaces all values by integer**

The best practice is to use the placeholder attribute in your case